# Adding and elements to Dataflow in ADF .NET SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

I am wondering if it is possible to create Data Flows using Azure Data Factory .NET SDK? I am able to create pipelines, and add a dataflow as ExecuteDataFlowActivity, however I am not able to add parameters, sources or transformations. Any documentation or samples are much appreciated:

```
        DataFactoryManagementClient client = ...
        DataFlowResource dataflow = new DataFlowResource { 
            Properties = new DataFlow
            {
                Description = dataFactoryName                    
            }                
        };
        
        client.DataFlows.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, dataFactoryName, dataflow);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but sometimes just go with the UI if you can. I would recommend to take look at on how ADF generates ARM templates for Data Flows and maybe you will change your mind=)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.mappingdataflow?view=azure-dotnet

Review docs, this object inherits DataFlow, so it should work in similar way.